# IE Input type Date not appearing as Date Picker

Tags: internet-explorer, date, datepicker

I am using the input type DATE in my HTML and everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but IE does not show the date picker.

When I use the JQuery Datepicker I get two date picker dialogs in Chrome and Firefox.

How can I fix the functionality where I can have the date input type and only have one popup for my form?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use a [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) so that the input type DATE has a consistent behaviour in all browsers. You can use this [webshim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html) as a polyfill.

Input type DATE is an HTML5 feature which is not supported by all browsers. In case you want to use the HTML5 feature not supported by your browser (which usually will be IE) then use two things:

- Feature Detection
- Polyfills

Feature Detection is the ability to determine if the HTML5 feature is supported or not by our browser. A good library for that is [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). What you can do with modernizr is to detect if any feature that you need is not supported and if not then you can conditionally load some javascript libraries that will implement that feature. Those libraries are called [Polyfills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)).

So for example if you want to use the  tag in IE 10 you could use the jqueryui.com controls to provide a date picker.

```
Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
    nope: "js/jquery-ui.custom.js",
    callback: function() {
      $("input[type=date]").datepicker();
    }
  });
```

Modernizr tests if the feature is supported, optionally you can use the nope to indicate if there is a library that you want to load ONLY if the feature is not supported, and callback is the code that will be called after the test and after loading the library.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5 and modernizr is being loaded but that code block does not work. What am I missing so that I can get the Modernizr.load() to work? Javascript Error: Unhandled exception at line 166, column 9 in http://localhost:31124/FormManagement/ExportFormsEXCEL

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'load'

Comment: If you are a .NET developer using Visual Studio and, the general 'Modernizr' NuGet package does NOT include the Modernizr.load().

I would like to tip .NETters to use an [alternative NuGet package 'Modernizr full'](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Modernizr.full/) that DOES include the load() function.

Comment: Note this line of code: `nope: "js/jquery-ui.custom.js"` change the path according to where the jquery file is located in your project