# Inputdate doesn't work on internet explorer 11 (blazor)

Tags: blazor

```html
<EditForm Model="test">

    <InputDate @bind-Value="value" id="inputdate"></InputDate>

</EditForm>
@code {
    DateTime? value = DateTime.Now;
}
```

hi everyone I am using blazor and i noticed that inputdate does not open the datapicker on ie, is there any way to fix it? if it doesn't exist, are there free libraries that allow me to manage the data on ie?

Comment: Please show the code using `inputdate`. Requests for recommendations of libraries or otherwise are defined as being off-topic for SO.

Comment: It's blazor server side? And which version of IE?

Comment: How it is related to C?

Comment: I am using version 11 of ie

Comment: [ASP.NET Core Blazor supported platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `type="date"` is not supported in Safari or Internet Explorer 11 (or earlier).

Input type DATE is an HTML5 feature that is not supported by all browsers. In case you want to use the HTML5 feature not supported by your browser. You can use a polyfill for example:

http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html

[(details)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30893387/1158845)